# React-cookie giving "Check the render method of `CookiesProvider`" error

Tags: reactjs, react-cookie

I'm trying to use cookies in my react app but cannot make react-cookie module to work. I'm using example from this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie

but it gives me the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>
> Check the render method of `CookiesProvider`.

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
//cookie
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';



const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
    <CookiesProvider>
        <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </CookiesProvider>,
    rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

app.js:

```
//cookies
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';

class App extends Component {
    displayName = App.name

    static propTypes = {
        cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const { cookies } = props;
        this.state = {
            name: cookies.get('name') || 'Ben'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Welcome} />
                <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default withCookies(App);
```

Comment: why I can't reproduce the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/914x4vz3nw you can see that I don't receive any error

Comment: i keep getting this error no matter what i do, Using ASP.Net Core 2.1

Answer (score -1):

You downloaded the wrong library. The library's name is `react-cookie` not `react-cookies`.